# Usign OS X SDK 10.7 with Xcode 7.3 and CMake

Tags: macos, sdk, xcode7, std

I have a serious issue getting Xcode 7.3 to compile a Project against Mac SDK 10.7 with LLVM (7+) and C++11. The source of the issue seems to be Xcode or the fact that I'm running OS X 10.11. Some colleagues of mine don't have the same issue compiling the same issue with older Xcode Versions (6). Here is the general setup:

The needed Libraries and Headers are linked with CMake. The Include paths of everything got checked multiple times. The created Xcode Project also seems to be ok, we've compared all important settings (C++ dialect, std library , target, defines etc) against systems where the project does compile.

The actual error comes when compiling vecLib source.It seems to be a set of random error messages I would trace back to the lack of c++ std headers.. Here are a few examples:

`Explicite specialization of non-template class 'complex'`

`Redifinition of complex as different kind of symbol`

Did anybody run into similar problems when working with newer Xcodes against older SDKs?

**EDIT**

Here is some more informations. After checking what was behind the redifinition, I found that for some odd reason, the complex definition that was interfering with the forward declaration in the file comes from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1. I think that the header is outdated or at least not compatible with c++11. I checked again what the compiler used and the lib / language (std=c++11 and stdlib=libc++) where correctly set. I have the strange feeling that the source in user/include isn't supposed to be included but I don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT 2**

I've checked the standard include paths with `cpp -v` and got the following list:

```
/usr/local/include
/Applications/XCode/.../XCodeDefault.xtoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/include
/Applications/XCode/.../XCodeDefault.xtoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks
/Library/Frameworks
```

The definition of complex in the Xcode toolchain (3rd entry) is the correct one, the definition in /usr/include is the one that seems to be used while compiling, leading to the error messages. The definition of `complex` uses structs.

What is the issue here? Is the issue that Xcode / Clang or what ever decides to go with usr/include instead of the toolchain include? I've checked the project settings and the compiler output and there was no explicit include of this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like AppleClang 7+ and libc++ just doesn't support vecLib from OS X SDK 10.7. I had to go back to Xcode 6 to get it to build.